# Conditional Statement Being Ignored

Tags: java, eclipse

Checkout the following snippet:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (v==yes_button) {

        //Toast.makeText(this, "All records have been deleted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        db.open();  
        db.deleteAll();
        db.close();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, home_screen_activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);  }


        else if (v==no_button){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, home_screen_activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);  }


}

}
```

For some reason, the else if portion is being ignored and the code runs as if it's not there, so even if the no button is clicked, the database is still deleted. It must be something simple I'm missing, but I can't seem to nail it down. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks for the input everyone, but I got the problem solved by renaming the no_button. Weird.

Comment: Why don't you use two separate event handlers for yes and no button?

Comment: I was going to, but, on a hunch, I renamed the button in the code segment that was being ignored, and voila! It works! :)

Answer (score 1):

Since `v` is an object and not a primitive type, the `==` comparison compares object locations in memory, rather than testing for equality. Instead, you need to modify your test to use the `.equals` method:

```
 if (v.equals(yes_button)) {
     ...
 } else {

 }
```

Also, if there's really only two alternatives, you can, as I have above, omit a test to see if the press was on the "no" button.

Comment: and not bad to mention, use proper indentation, and follow java code conventions..

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It's weird, though, I have used the exact same construction in my other activities and it works fine. Also, I thought the "equals" method was used to evaluate strings?

Comment: Thanks again, but changing it per your suggestions still didn't do anything. But, I did get the code to work by renaming the no-button. I don't know why it works now, but it does.

Answer (score 0):

In android, I usually check by the `R.id.`

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int viewID = v.getId();

    if (viewID == R.id.yes_button) {

    } else if (newID == R.id.no_button) {
```